# How do I write a for loop that stops at every third index item, and continues inserting items to a new (carousel) page?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
        page.listSuccess = function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data && data.items) {
            var itemsQty = Math.ceil(data.items.length / 3);

            for (var index = 0; index < itemsQty; index++) {
                var itemData = {};
                var itemClone = page.insertItemDOM(itemData);

                if (index == 0) {
                    itemClone.addClass("active");
                    console.log(itemClone);
                }
            }
        }
        for (var index = 0; index < data.items.length; index++) {
            var testimonialData = {}
            testimonialData.title = data.items[index].title;
            testimonialData.body = data.items[index].body;
            testimonialData.starRating = data.items[index].starRating;
            testimonialData.id = data.items[index].id;
            page.insertTestimonialDOM(testimonialData);                
        }
    }
```

At the moment, this code inserts all(5) my testimonials on one page. I need three per page, but I'm unsure as to how to go about it.

itemClone = a page on the carousel

testimonialData = a testimonial

insertItemDOM function =

```
        page.insertItemDOM = function (itemData) {
        var newItem = $($("#itemTemplate").html()).clone();
        var targetLoc = $('.carousel-inner');
        targetLoc.attr("data-target", "true");
        targetLoc.append(newItem);

        return newItem;
    }
```

insertTestimonialDOM function =

```
        page.insertTestimonialDOM = function (testimonialData) {
        var newTemplate = $($("#testimonialTemplate").html()).clone();           

        newTemplate.find('.title').html(testimonialData.title);
        newTemplate.find('.body').html(testimonialData.body);
        newTemplate.find('.starRating').html(testimonialData.starRating);

        var targetLoc = $('.carousel-inner');
        targetLoc.attr("data-target", "true");
        targetLoc.append(newTemplate);

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the modulo operator.

Comment: Does `insertTestimonialDOM` insert in the active `itemClone` or in the last created one?

Comment: how do you switch from one page to another explain that to me. I can explain the concept but I cannot really understand your code you have given above.

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy I'm using a carousel plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the concept for you. What you want is after every 3 loop execution the loop shall work it again and enter details in a new page.

Let's make two function.

```
var index; 
var theinitial = function(z)
{
 index = z
 var counter = 1;
 insertionfunction();
}

var insertionfunction = function()
{
    for (var zzz = index; zzz < data.items.length; zzz++) {

        if (counter <= 3)
              {
                itemClone = page.insertItemDOM(itemData);
              }
        else
          {
            theinitial(zzz);   
          } 

}
```

Here the first request you make to 'theinitial function' with 1 as value of z then the function will call the insertion function and now the loop will run for 3 times then after three times the value of zzz is used to call the initial function again. Now your index is 4, hence the loop will start from 4th element and run for 3 more times as counter is reinitialized to 1.

I don't really know how your page insertion thing works therefore I am explaining the concept to you.